# Detect that the system is locked

Tags: lock-screen

I want to detect if Ubuntu 19.10 screen screensaver is locked at a particular time, and find out how long it has been in this state.

If the system is locked for a certain amount of time (whether left unattended or not), a certain script will be run (for example, you may want to shot down a workstation after one day so that energy is not wasted).

How can I detect the lock screen and its time duration?

Comment: I found some old solutions using dbus. But it seems Ubuntu's dbus output format changes from version to version.  I want a reliable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gnome-screensaver-command`:

```
       gnome-screensaver-command - controls GNOME screensaver

SYNOPSIS

       gnome-screensaver-command [OPTION...]

DESCRIPTION

       gnome-screensaver-command  is a tool for controlling an already running instance of gnome-
       screensaver.
```

Comment: You got it! gnome-screensaver-command -q tells if the screen is locked and -t option tells  the time duration it has been active. The utility has to be installed.